# How to generate files on the client file system using oracle UTL_FILE package

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, utl-file

I'd like to know, if is it possible to generate and retrieve the file using `UTL_FILE` package in oracle on the client side?

Comment: No, `UTL_FILE` access only the file system on database server. But you may share such directory by NFS or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `UTL_FILE` operates with files on a server, stored in a directory accessible to Oracle. Therefore, you should `CREATE DIRECTORY` (oracle object) which points to a local directory (possibly, using UNC), grant required privileges (`READ, WRITE` most probably) and use that directory while working with `UTL_FILE`.